# How can I copy photos from a Sony mobile phone to iPad?

Tags: ipad, photos, data-transfer

How can I copy Sony mobile phone's photos to iPad?

Note: I have the camera adaptor cable already, that is used to connect to iPad but it doesn't work for Sony XPeria Z mobile phone. When I try to connect, the iPad gives an `insufficient power for that device` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't use the adaptor/cable for this. Alternatively you can email the photos to an account configured on the iPad or install Dropbox on both devices and use this for syncing photos.